# Live USB Ubuntu on second partition

Tags: partitioning, live-usb

Is it possible to put a live ubuntu installation on the *second* partition of a flash drive?

I have a flash drive with 2 partitions:

- The first one is ~10GB formatted FAT32 for storing files on in windows.
- The second is ~5GB and I want to put a live ubuntu on it with a persistence file.

Comment: Theoretically yes, but it would be complicated and involve more hacking than is probably worth it. How badly do you need to be able to do this?

Comment: @MGodby I can get by without this, it is just a convenience that would be nice to have I suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this could theoretically be done, it would involve some hacking around with manual grub installation and set up. As an alternative, you could move your existing FAT32 partition towards the end of the drive to allow for installation of live USB images to the beginning of the flash drive.

First, shrink your existing FAT32 partition down far enough to ensure that there is enough free space for the live OS image, then use a partition manager to move this partition towards the end of the partition table until there is enough free space at the beginning to do your live OS installation.

You could use a program like Gparted to accomplish this quite easily.

```
sudo apt-get -y install gparted
sudo gparted
```

Alternatively, you can backup your files from the USB flash drive, format the entire flash drive as FAT32, install the live USB image onto the flash drive via unetbootin, then create a folder at the root of your USB drive called "my files" or whatever you'd like, then store your files in there.

Note: I know this to work for Ubuntu Live USBs, but I cannot guarantee that it will work for non-debian distributions. For instance, Fedora Live USB does not work correctly when created from unetbootin.

Installing unetbootin:

```
sudo apt-get -y install unetbootin
```

Comment: Could I then swap them back around afterwards?

Comment: Not if you want the live OS partition(s) to still work. The GRUB installation at the beginning of the drive points to a specific location from which to begin loading the OS. Do you need the live OS to be on the second partition specifically for some reason?

Comment: I wanted it to be on the second partition so that I could use the first partition for storing files on in windows - windows doesn't support multiple partitions on removable drives :(

Comment: What version of Windows are you using? I remember doing something exactly like this and having it work perfectly.

Comment: I am using Windows 7, and an ubuntu virtual machine (using virtualbox) to do all the linux based stuff.

Comment: I have never had a problem getting Windows 7 to recognize multiple partitions on a removable drive. Are you basing this on theory, or have you tried what I said and had it not work?

Comment: I have tried it - I formatted the second partition as FAT32 in Linux and then windows only saw the first of the two partitions.

Comment: I have added another solution to my answer that involves using a single partition for both purposes.